# "Embed Google Docs Folders in a Google Site" script returns error. Is now required an additional permission to run it?

Tags: google-apps-script

I added the "Embed Google Docs Folders in a Google Site" from de Google Spreadsheet script gallery and allowed to run, add the folder id and the URL of a Google Site page. It runs fine for files where I'm the owner or an editor but when I'm a viewer an error occurs and the following error message is displayed

You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 31)

The above occurred both with a Google Apps account and with a consumer account.

I'm wondering if an additional permission is required or if there is a another way to get the owner of docs shared with me.

Thanks in advance,
Rubén

Comment: Just found [issue 1258](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1258). I think that it's about the same problem.

Comment: At this time, Google Sites include an official gadget to list files in a Google Drive folder, but this only includes the file name and date and user that did the last modification. By the other hand, the script gallery is now the add-on store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 1258:  DocsList and View only Acccess](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1258#c4) was marked "WorkingAsIntended" August 22, 2012.

Following Google's sharing model, "Read Only" access does not give permissions to see document owners' names or ids.

Comment: DocsList was deprecated in April 2015, use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) instead. The security restrictions remain, however.